# Open a new tab with "hello world" on it

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-overlay

How to open new tab, and create a new HTML document in it? Preferably using old restart-required API, like `Components.classes`, `Components.interfaces` stuff, but any way that works is fine.

Comment: What is going to work *for you* will depend on the type of add-on you are writing. What you have stated implies that you are writing a Overlay/XUL add-on. Is that correct?  If so, you should **seriously** consider writing a WebExtension, or Add-on SDK based add-on. See the [Introduction to Firefox add-ons in documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/introduction-to-firefox-add-ons/13574/introduction#t=201609290133319078047).

Comment: Yes, I have Overlay/XUL addons. I considered moving them, but didn't had enough time to do so. Things I need to know in order to migrate are (1) Is it possible to set global variables / access extensions state via browser console in new extensions? and (2) Is there still an alternative to nsIStreamListener/TracingListener in the newer api?

Comment: In the Add-on SDK you can do almost anything in JavaScript which you could do in Overlay or bootstrap add-on (Obviously not *chrome.manifest* `overlay`s).  The add-on SDK is a bootstrapped add-on with a wrapper.  You can break out of the wrapper when you have things you want to do which are not directly supported by the Add-on SDK APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of my add-ons, I use the following code to open a URL in either a tab or a window:

```js
/**
 * Open a URL in a window or a tab.
 */
 function openUrlInWindowOrTab(url, titleText, inWindow, makeTabActive) {
    // Default: in tab; tab not activated
    if(typeof (url) !== "string" ) {
        return;
    }//else
    //  Add/remove a "/" to comment/un-comment the code appropriate for your add-on type.
    /* Add-on SDK:
    let activeWindow = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    //*/
    //* Overlay and bootstrap (from almost any context/scope):
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm"); //Services
    let activeWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");        
    //*/
    let gBrowser = activeWindow.gBrowser;

    if(inWindow) {
        // Set default title
        titleText = (typeof titleText === "string") ? titleText : "Opened by [Your add-on]";
        //Open a window
        return activeWindow.open(url, titleText);
    } else {
        //Open a tab
        let newTab = gBrowser.addTab(url);
        if(makeTabActive) {
            //Make the tab active
            gBrowser.selectedTab = newTab;
        }
        return newTab;
    }
}
```

The above should work in Overlay and Bootstrapped add-ons. It can also work in the Add-on SDK by uncommenting the code for the Add-on SDK and commenting out the Overlay/bootstrapped code (the line(s) that get the `activeWindow`).  However, for the Add-on SDK, it would be better to use the SDK specific APIs.

If you want it to say "Hello World" in the new tab, then provide an HTML file in your `chrome/content` directory and use an appropriate URL for it (e.g. `chrome://[as defined in your chrome.manifest]/content/helloWorld.html`), as defined for your add-on in a [`content` line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#content-instruction) in your [*chrome.manifest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration).